# ECMAScript 6 features available in Node.js 0.12

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8, ecmascript-6

A new stable release of Node.js (0.12) has landed recently with an upgraded Google's v8 JavaScript engine, *v3.28.73*.

### What ECMAScript 6 features are currently present in Node.js, without using the `--harmony` flag?

I have checked several sites claiming to list the ES 6 features but all of them seem out of date - most prominently, [this table](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#node) (**Update:** *now updated with current Node.js status as of 0.12*), because several of the features are listed as requiring the `--harmony` flag while I found some of them being enabled by default (Maps, Sets, Symbols, to name a few). **Update**: [Node specific tables](http://node.green/) have since been made available

Also, trying to google this information purely for the v8 engine gives too up-to-date information - current v8 release is *4.2.**, which is quite ahead of what Node.js uses.

My hopes are that this question (and its answers) will become a comprehensive summary on what ES 6 features are now available to Node.js developers.

### ES 6 features enabled in Node.js 0.12 I currently know of:

- Maps, Sets / WeakMaps, WeakSets
- Symbols
- Object.observe
- Promises
- Number

  - .isInteger
  - .isSafeInteger
  - .isNaN
  - .EPSILON
  - .MIN_SAFE_INTEGER
  - .MAX_SAFE_INTEGER
- Math

  - .clz32
  - .imul
  - .sign
  - .log10
  - .log2
  - .log1p
  - .expm1
  - .cosh
  - .sinh
  - .tanh
  - .acosh
  - .asinh
  - .atanh
  - .trunc
  - .fround
  - .cbrt
  - .hypot

Comment: *"My hopes are that this question (and its answers) will become a comprehensive summary on what ES 6 features are now available to Node.js developers."*  - The chances are that it will simply become a disorganized mess ... that is just as out-of-date as all of the other resources!!  Unless you 1) self answer and 2) take the time to curate the other answers into yours.  If you are prepared to do that work, then it might be more appropriate to do it in a blog.

Comment: Or just switch to [io.js](https://iojs.org/) (which ships with a far more up to date V8 version) and keep an eye on the [ES6 on io.js page](https://iojs.org/es6.html).

Comment: I don't have a blog (- not sure if happy or sad smile here -). The answer that gets all of the features listed for the versions mentioned (they are not infinite!) will get accepted, be it an answer of mine or someone else's. Alternatively, the answer with most upvotes wins.

Comment: @StephenC Actually I think this is a good question. Specially considering the fact that node documentation is really poor. Let's see it'll become disorganized mess or not. We can't  foresee the future.

Comment: Curated ES6 compatibility table: http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/

Comment: Kangax's compat tables appear to have been [last updated with Node 0.11.14](https://github.com/kangax/compat-table/blob/afd609160bc846bbe96b15bb563285bc9d6ba455/data-es6.js#L307-L313), but they are [open source](https://github.com/kangax/compat-table/) and could be run with 0.12 manually.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski interesting, it is odd that I can't find an issue/PR regarding Node 0.12. **edit:** filed an [issue](https://github.com/kangax/compat-table/issues/427).

Comment: @RobertRossmann - Anyone can have a blog.  I'm not doubting your goal.  It is just that I don't think this will work ... unless someone (i.e. >>you<<) puts in the >>effort<< to make it work work.

Comment: You might find this useful:

[ECMAScript compatibility table](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6)

Comment: See http://node.green/

Answer (score 250, accepted):

**Features without `--harmony` flag:**

- ["for-of" loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)
- [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set), [WeakMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap), [WeakSet](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakSet) (already specified in question)
- [Symbol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol) (already specified in question)
- [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) (already specified in question)
- Array methods:

  - [.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/keys)
  - [.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/values)
  - [.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/entries)
  - [[Symbol.iterator]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/@@iterator)
- Object:

  - [.observe()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/observe) (initially was [planned for ES7](http://bocoup.com/weblog/javascript-object-observe/), but was [removed from the spec entirely](https://esdiscuss.org/topic/an-update-on-object-observe) on November 2, 2015)
  - [.is()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/is)
  - [.setPrototypeOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf)
  - [.getOwnPropertySymbols()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertySymbols)
  - .getNotifier() (not es6, example [here](http://bocoup.com/weblog/javascript-object-observe/))
  - .apply() and .call() (not es6, same purpose as Funciton.prototype.call and Function.prototype.apply)
- Number properties and methods (already specified in question)

  - [.isInteger()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isInteger)
  - [.isSafeInteger()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isSafeInteger)
  - [.isNaN()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN)
  - [.isFinite()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isFinite)
  - [EPSILON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/EPSILON)
  - [MIN_SAFE_INTEGER](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MIN_SAFE_INTEGER)
  - [MAX_SAFE_INTEGER](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER)
- Math methods ([a lot of them](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math)) (already specified in question)
- [constants](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const)

I thinks that's all that we have without `--harmony` flag.

**Features with `--harmony` flag:**

- [generators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*)
- [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) (without need of `--harmony_arrow_functions` flag in contrast to `io.js`)
- [let variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) - only in `strict mode`
- [Binary and octal literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar)
- String methods:

  - [.contains()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) (was replaced by `includes()` in actual ES6 specification)
  - [.startsWith()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith)
  - [.endsWith()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith)
  - [.codePointAt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/codePointAt)
  - [.repeat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat)
  - [.normalize()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize)
  - [String.fromCodePoint](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCodePoint)
- [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) (behind the `--harmony-proxies` flag)

I think that's all. Maybe if I forgot something - I'll add it later to the list.

Comment: This is exactly the kind of answer I was hoping to get - clean, and with links to docs/examples! Extra points for listing features under the `--harmony` flag.:)

Comment: String templates are out with or without `--harmony`? As in the back tick `${varname}` string syntax?

Comment: @Sukima Node v0.12 does not support [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings), nor with `--harmony` flag, nor without it. But `iojs`  supports them without need of any flags.

Comment: Does nodejs have this documented anywhere?  It is very useful.

Comment: Hmm...  My run failed with a constant without the harmony flag just now.  Node v0.12.2

Comment: @JonRed Maybe your run failed by another reason, not because of a constant. I have just tried it and my run works pretty well.

Comment: @alexpods - tested again this morning with a basic example, you're dead right.  Thank you.

Comment: Per [this thread](https://esdiscuss.org/topic/an-update-on-object-observe), Object.observe is going the way of the dinosaur

Comment: @HaiPhan Thanks for reminding! I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 4):

ES6 features trickle down to Node in phases. Node uses Google's V8 as the JavaScript engine. A feature being supported in Node means it first has to be implemented in V8 and then Node team has to incorporate it in Node.js.

The team at Google releases a new version of V8 roughly every six weeks, and then it's up to the Node team to take it into use.

Manually curated lists of language features are nice but can become outdated quickly. Node 0.12 is not that in flux anymore, but typically manually curated list becomse obsolete as soon as a new version of Node is rolled out.

Here are two alternate ways to check what features a Node version supports, without relying on a static list. For further reading and more detailed examples of using these, you can check ["How to check if Node.js supports ES 6 language feature"](http://bytearcher.com/articles/how-to-check-if-node-implements-es6-language-feature/)

#### #1 Easy - compatibility table

A dynamically generated list that relies on small tests to confirm the presence of a language feature stays better up to date. One such popular list is kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/. We are interested only in Node features, so you can use

http://node.green

that leverages the same data as the kangax site.

#### #2 Hard - backtrack V8 version

Node uses V8 engine, so determining which version of V8 is included in Node tells us what ES6 language features are supported. You can find out which version of V8 was bundled in Node with `node -p process.versions.v8`.

```
$ node -p process.versions.v8
4.6.85.31
```

Then using Google's V8 project resources you can find which features are implemented in each version. The V8 project keeps an [issue tracker](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/list?can=1&q=label%3Aharmony) where you can find ES6+beyond features marked with the *harmony* label.