# es6 support in a current node version

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, koa

What es6 features can I use when I run a file with `--harmony` flag? Or where can I find any details about it?

My versions:

[image]

Cheers!

Comment: read about it from the biased experts: https://iojs.org/en/es6.html

Comment: Have a look at [io.js](https://iojs.org) :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can find the list of features enabled with and without `--harmony` here in another similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28388885/ecmascript-6-features-available-in-node-js-0-12)

This is the official [list](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/ES6-(a.k.a.-Harmony)-Features-Implemented-in-V8-and-Available-in-Node). However, you're recommended not to use `--harmony` because it enables all the experimental features.