# Using String.raw() with Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I'm working on a Node.js app with and I would like to use [String.raw()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/raw) which is part of the ES 6 standard.

However, when using it as in the documentation:

```
text = String.raw`Hi\n${2+3}!` + text.slice(2);
```

It returns `SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL` for the character after `String.raw`.

I think that there is a problem because String.raw() is a new technology only available for Chrome and Firefox yet. However, can I use it in Node.js and how?

Comment: Might be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28388885/ecmascript-6-features-available-in-node-js-0-12 `raw()` doesn't seem to be in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The grave character after raw denotes template strings, which is a feature in ES6 Harmony. You can invoke node with --harmony flag, but this feature is not yet implemented. This is the reason of the syntax error. Raw strings are unsupported too.
If you want experimenting with this feature in server side, check out [io.js](https://iojs.org/en/index.html), which is a fork of node, but with many ES6 features implemented and enabled by default.