# Node / Mongo built-in promises

Tags: node.js, promise

I am on Node 0.12.x working with the native Mongo driver. My original work was to promisify Mongo using Bluebird however I quickly realized that Mongo has built-in promises for the most part. This then led me to realize I have a built-in global `Promise` object to work with however I am unclear if this is native to JS or added by the es6 promise library that Mongo uses. Can someone clarify this? I am not sure which API docs to look at to see its features.

Comment: Mongoose uses mpromise. You can (and probably should) use a library like bluebird until native promises become better supported and reasonably fast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Native MongoDB driver is using `es6-promise` for deployment and `bluebird` for development https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/2.0/package.json

Both `Node.js` and `io.js` implementations of native promises are still incomplete, so you shouldn't rely on them.

`bluebird` is the most popular choice.

Comment: So the global Promise object I am finding is Node's partial implementation?

Comment: @Yashua yes it is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28388885/ecmascript-6-features-available-in-node-js-0-12