# Destructuring an array in a function fails with "let is not defined"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I'd like to destructure an array inside a function.

The following example passes an array as a single argument, then attempts to destructure the argument inside the function. Seems simple enough, but node throws an error.

```
// volume.js
function volume(box) {
  let [x,y,z] = box;
  return x * y * z;
}

volume([2,3,4]);
```

Running that with `$ node volume.js` (v5.1.1) returns this error:

```
./volume.js:2
  let [x,y,z] = box;
  ^

ReferenceError: let is not defined
    at volume (./volume.js:2:3)
    at Object.<anonymous> (./volume.js:5:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:425:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:432:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:313:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:457:10)
    at startup (node.js:138:18)
    at node.js:974:3
```

There are other ways to solve this, but I don't understand why the above example doesn't work. Why does this throw an error? How can `let` be undefined?

Comment: The syntax seems correct. Works in Firefox. Do you still need to set a flag in node to get ES6 features?

Comment: Based on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28389178/1106925) from earlier this year (and edited last month), you need the `--harmony` flag for `let`. Are you using that flag?

Comment: The reason I say that is because of this page: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/es6/ I tried using `node --harmony` and also `node --harmony_destructuring` with the destructuring assignment and both gave the same error as you're getting using node 4.2.2. With babel, it compiles correctly however.

Comment: Running with `--harmony` didn't change anything. Also, I don't believe we need the harmony flag anymore. Node/JS moves very fast, the v0.12 release mentioned in that answer is several major releases old by now.

Comment: Actually @Shashank, that helped. Adding "use strict" (thought that was obsolete) and using the `--harmony_destructuring` flag worked.

Comment: @joemaller cool I didn't know use strict was necessary to enable the feature so you have taught me something :) though I kind of wonder why it's necessary to do that lol.

Comment: ps, once destructuring is available in node, you can write it as `function volume([x,y,z]) { return x * y * z; }` or even better `const volume = ([x,y,z]) => x * y * z;`

Answer (score 1):

Destructuring doesn't work with vanilla node v5.1.x because destructuring is still considered an "in-progress" feature.

The `let is not defined` ReferenceError is raised because block scope declarations are currently [limited to strict mode](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/es6/#ref-1).

So, for the above code to work, node needs to be invoked with the `harmony_destructuring` flag and the code needs to be running in strict mode. Add `"use strict"` to the top of the file and run this:

```
$ node --harmony_destructuring ./volume.js
```

Node also offers a `--use_strict` flag, but I prefer to declare that per file.

The [node.js documentation](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/es6/) (current as of v5.1.1, as cited by @Shashank in comments), ES6/ES2015 features are divided up into three categories:

- **Shipping** - enabled by default
- **Staged** - almost ready, bulk-enabled with the `--harmony` flag.
- **In progress** - experimental, can be individually enabled

Running node with the harmony flag, `node --harmony` only enables Staged features. In Progress features like destructuring need to be individually enabled. Here's the list of the in progress flags in node v.5.1.1:

- `--harmony_modules` - harmony modules
- `--harmony_regexps` - harmony regular expression extensions
- `--harmony_proxies` - harmony proxies
- `--harmony_sloppy_function` - harmony sloppy function block scoping
- `--harmony_sloppy_let` - harmony let in sloppy mode
- `--harmony_unicode_regexps` - harmony unicode regexps
- `--harmony_reflect` - harmony Reflect API
- `--harmony_destructuring` - harmony destructuring
- `--harmony_default_parameters` - harmony default parameters
- `--harmony_sharedarraybuffer` - harmony sharedarraybuffer
- `--harmony_atomics` - harmony atomics
- `--harmony_simd` - harmony simd