# SyntaxError: Unexpected token => Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

This scripts work on Windows 10 Nodejs but not on Ubuntu Nodejs v0.12

```
bot.on("message", msg => {
 // Content
});
```

Comment: Upgrade your nodejs version.

Comment: You need at least version 4.4.5 to use arrow functions. http://node.green/#arrow-functions

Comment: Or start your node with the parameter `--harmony` to enable some more ES6 features. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/28389178/1169798

Answer (score 4):

the arrow function => are ES6 functions, which you can't use with ES5 which was the default for node under 4.4.5 version.
On windows you must have installed the latest version of node, which supports that type of functions

Comment: `==>` should probably be `=>`

Comment: Thanks TimoSta for that, I overlooked that.